# Why enter laravel loop data max 40 row?

Tags: laravel, foreach, insert

I created a store function on my controller. At the time I will enter data with just one submit, only indexed up to 40 data will be entered. While those 40 and above do not enter the database. Why did this happen? What's the solution? Please i need help.
Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks

I am use Laravel 5.6

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

      foreach($request->quantity as $quantity){
        if($quantity == NULL){

        }
        if($quantity != NULL){
          $data = new KomponenOlahan;
          $data->quantity = $quantity;
          $harga_satuan_mu = Input::get('harga_satuan_mu');
          $total = $quantity*$harga_satuan_mu;
          $data->kode_proyek = Input::get('kode_proyek');
          $data->nama_proyek = Input::get('nama_proyek');
          $data->kode_panel = Input::get('kode_panel');
          $data->nama_panel = Input::get('nama_panel');
          $data->schedule_kirim = Input::get('schedule_kirim');
          $data->nama_sales = Input::get('nama_sales');
          $data->ukuran_panel = Input::get('ukuran_panel');
          $data->ref = Input::get('ref');
          $data->type = Input::get('type');
          $data->komponen_bantu = Input::get('komponen_bantu');
          $data->nama_komponen = Input::get('nama_komponen');
          $data->spek = Input::get('spek');
          $data->satuan = Input::get('satuan');
          $data->diskon = Input::get('diskon');
          $data->harga = Input::get('harga');
          $data->pole = Input::get('pole');
          $data->ka = Input::get('ka');
          $data->ampere = Input::get('ampere');
          $data->quantity = $quantity;
          $data->harga_satuan_mu = $harga_satuan_mu;
          $data->harga_satuan_mb = Input::get('harga_satuan_mb');
          $data->harga_satuan_lb_oh = Input::get('harga_satuan_lb_oh');
          $data->id_estimasi = Input::get('id_estimasi');
          $data->nama_estimasi = Input::get('nama_estimasi');
          $data->total = $total;
          $data->trigger_bom = Input::get('trigger_bom');

          $data->save();
        }

      }
```

My View

```
 <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="kode_proyek" hidden value="{{$panel->kode_projek}}">

etc....
```

My View
[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ecwQ.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `$data->save();` after if loop /?

Comment: Same max 40 row. I have 300 row. 
when I enter data in row 41, the data cannot enter until row 300

Answer (score 1):

You can save it first to array then use bulk insert.

Inserting data 1 by 1 will slow your application.

```
$insertArray = array();

foreach($request->quantity as $quantity){
  if($quantity == NULL){
    $insertArray[] = array(
      'quantity' => $quantity,
      'harga_satuan_mu ' => Input::get('harga_satuan_mu'),
      .... // add other fields

    )
  }
}
KomponenOlahan::insert($insertArray);
```

Comment: row 41, if i insert value, the value didn't insert to database